# How to dynamically insert an unknown number of inserts into a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to add an unknown number of inserts (defined by a input_list) into predefined strings sets (words). These input_lists and words will change, but all input values will be provided and the words function will always be split on ';' and will need the input_list added in order at each '{}'.

For example:

```
input_list = ['input', 'second', 1, 'input2', 'third', 4, 'input3', 'fourth', 5]
words =  'this is my {} string1;this will be my {} input string {}'
```

should generate:

```
'this is my input string1'
'this will be my second input string 1'
'this is my input2 string'
'this will be my third input string 4'
'this is my input3 string'
'this will be my fourth input string 5'
```

I have been playing with something along the lines of:

```
input_counter = 0

words = words.split(';')
variation = len(input_list)/len(words)

for similar in range(0, variation):
    for phrase in words:
        new_count = len(phrase.split('{}'))
        print(phrase.format(input_list[input_counter:input_counter+new_count]))
        input_counter += new_count
```

but have been unable to find a way to add an unknown number (a list) of input values into the string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for the edit Johnny Mopp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- Renamed the list of lines to be formatted to `lines`
- Based control of the outer loop explicitly on how much of `input_list` is left to use
- Want the number of `{}` in the line to be filled in; this is one less than how many parts you get by splitting on `{}`
- Use `*` to pass not the list of values to fill the format with but each list item as a separate argument

Which gets us to here:

```
lines = words.split(';')
while input_counter < len(input_list):
    for phrase in lines:
        new_count = len(phrase.split('{}')) - 1
        print(phrase.format(*input_list[input_counter:input_counter+new_count]))
        input_counter += new_count
```

Comment: Perfect! That '*' action is a new one to me and have only really seen it used with zip (which i totally tried earlier XD)

Answer (score 1):

The count of `{}` can be had in each word. 
With this you have the number of parameters to be substituted for in the word and can perform slices accordingly on the `input_list`

```py
words = words.split(';')
params = input_list[:]

while params:
  for w in words:
    num_vars = w.count('{}')
    args, params = params[:num_vars], params[num_vars:]
    print(w.format(*args))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?
Provided words always has same inputs like above and input list can be divided into sections like above

https://onlinegdb.com/B1EZFB-xH

```
input_list = ['input', 'second', 1, 'input2', 'third', 4, 'input3', 'fourth', 5]
words =  'this is my {} string;this will be my {} input string {}'
count = int(len(input_list)/3)
words = words.split(';')
print(words)
iter = 0
for i in range(count):
    print(words[0].format(input_list[iter]))
    print(words[1].format(input_list[iter+1], input_list[iter+2]))
    iter += 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
input_list = ['input', 'second', 1, 'input2', 'third', 4, 'input3', 'fourth', 5]
words =  'this is my {} string1;this will be my {} input string {}'

placeholders = words.count('{}')

# Splitting the input list based on how many values go into the string
inputs = [
    input_list[i:i+placeholders]
    for i in range(0, len(input_list), placeholders)
]
'''
inputs = [
    ['input', 'second', 1], 
    ['input2', 'third', 4],
    ['input3', 'fourth', 5]
]
'''

for input in inputs:
    # place the inputs in the {} and split it at ; then join it back with \n
    print('\n'.join(words.format(*input).split(';')))
    print()
```

Output:

```py
this is my input string1
this will be my second input string 1

this is my input2 string1
this will be my third input string 4

this is my input3 string1
this will be my fourth input string 5
```

Comment: Assumes that `;` does not appear in `input_list`.

Comment: How about when the input don't have uniform length? e.g. say first string has 2 template parameters to be substituted, second has 3 and not everyone of them having 3 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
x = []

input_list = ['input', 'second', 1, 'input2', 'third', 4, 'input3', 'fourth', 5]
words =  'this is my {} string;this will be my {} input string {}'

variation = len(input_list)//3
words = words.split(';')

for i in range(variation):
    x.append(words[0].replace('{}', str(input_list[i*3])))
    x.append(words[1].split('{}')[0]+str(input_list[(i*3)+1])+words[1].split('{}')[1]+str(input_list[(i*3)+2]))
print(x)
```

output:

```
['this is my input string',
 'this will be my second input string 1',
 'this is my input2 string',
 'this will be my third input string 4',
 'this is my input3 string',
 'this will be my fourth input string 5']
```